# Strange characters in Linux console

Tags: linux, characters, linux-terminal

I don't know how I've exactly managed to do this, but when I now invoke some commands (like man `man` or `less`) I see strange ESC[1 characters on the screen. It looks like this:

[image]

The interesting part is that other commands (like `more`) display the console text properly. What could be the case of this behavior and how can I fix it?

Note: I could probably fix this by rebooting, but I'm in a chrooted environment installing the OS and I'd rather like to avoid any restarts. Also, I'm just curious, what happened.

Comment: Does running `reset` help?

Comment: @new123456 unfortunately no

Comment: Do you happen to be using a shell that is not color compatible? Those `ESC[` characters look to me like ANSI color codes.

Comment: Does `unset LESS` help, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the LESS environment variable that got reset.

Before applying the fix, there was no LESS env variable at all.

After applying the fix,  (running env-update and source /etc/profile), the LESS value is "-R -M --shift 5"

`-R --raw-control-chars   - output "raw" control characters.`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your TERM setting is wrong.

Character sequences like "ESC [ 1 m" are ANSI sequences that cause the terminal/console to display text in bold or various colours.

Programs like `man` use your TERM setting to translate the manual pages from their source format (troff I think) into something your terminal/console can display.